# How do I add space to LVM's root partition without shutting down my VM?

Tags: partitioning, vmware, lvm, virtualization

I'm using vmware and want to add space to a VM without shutting down the system by simply adding space to the existing drive. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

1. In the VMWare consore, extend the drive
2. Use `fdisk` or `cfdisk` or `parted` to create a new primary partition with type `8e/lvm` (we'll call it `/dev/sda3` for now)
3. Tell the system about the new partition: `sudo partprobe /dev/sda3`
4. Make the new partition an lvm physical volume: `sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3`
5. Add the new physical volume to your volume group: `sudo vgextend $VGName /dev/sda3`
6. Increase the size of your logical volume: `sudo lvextend -L+10G /dev/$VGName/root`
7. Increase the size of your file system: `sudo resize2fs /dev/$VGName/root`

It may be easier to simply add additional drives to the VM and use them as physical volumes. That would clutter the VM storage area with more VMDKs. This solution is a bit messier in the vm.