# Move space from one partition to the other

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I have tried to move the space from one partition to the other using GParted.

[image: GParted]

But it is not working out for me, the disk seems locked (considering the key), and I have tried to unmount it:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sda5
umount: /dev/sda5: not mounted
```

How can I move the 10GB to /dev/sda5?

Comment: The fact that the current installation uses LVM means that the answer suggested by Pilot6 as a duplicate is *not* a good model to follow. There are other relevant questions and answers, though; see my answer for some links. I don't think any of those is really a 100% perfect duplicate, though.

Comment: The solution provided by [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) did not provide any help. The suggestions given by @RodSmith did prove helpful.

Comment: Ì believe it all boiled down to being part of the same mount point.

Comment: From which partition or volume do you want to move space to which partition or volume? The (likely duplicated) answer depends on whether you want to resize an LVM volume or an LVM container.

Comment: Intention was to move space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda5

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the space from `/dev/sda3` to `/dev/sda5`, then rather than resize partitions, I recommend you use LVM tools to expand the volume group, and to then add logical volumes or increase the size of existing logical volumes. There are numerous references online to how to do this, such as:

- [Adding Disks With LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458476/adding-disks-with-lvm)
- [How to grow LVM partition to include newly released partition (now unallocated space)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611431/how-to-grow-lvm-partition-to-include-newly-released-partition-now-unallocated-s)
- [How do I add space to LVM's root partition without shutting down my VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531816/how-do-i-add-space-to-lvms-root-partition-without-shutting-down-my-vm)