# Gparted merge unallocated space with /dev/sda7

Tags: partitioning, lvm

How can I merge the unallocated space (selected in blue) to /dev/sda7 ? I shrank disk /dev/sda5 to create 100 GB free space.

I've created a Live USB with Gparted and I see all the partitions I have.

I want to merge all the unallocated space with /dev/sda7 (Fedora). How can I achieve this?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the screen shot.

There is no way you can directly merge the free space with sda7. You first need to merge it with sda6, shrink that and then merge it with sda7. The unallocated space needs to be adjacent to sda7 in order to merge them together.

Comment: This would be true of a regular partition, but as the partition to be extended is LVM, there are better options. LVM admittedly adds to the learning curve, but once it's learned, it makes tasks like this both easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

As `/dev/sda7` is an LVM, the easiest way to do what you want is to *not* merge the spaces directly; instead, you should create a new LVM physical volume (PV; that is, a new partition) in the unallocated space, add it to the LVM volume group (VG), and then add new logical volumes (LVs) or extend existing LVs. Several questions and answers on this site describe similar procedures, such as:

- [Adding Disks With LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458476/adding-disks-with-lvm)
- [How do I add space to LVM's root partition without shutting down my VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531816/how-do-i-add-space-to-lvms-root-partition-without-shutting-down-my-vm)

The `system-config-lvm` tool may be helpful, too; it's a GUI front-end to many of the LVM utilities.

Comment: KDE Partition Manager might also be helpful. It supports operations on PVs, VGs, LVs including encrypted PVs and LVs.